# Undefined index: email in C:\Apache24\htdocs\checkup.php on line 10

Tags: php, html

i am new in php and i m creating a login system in my website every thing is working fine but 2 error are appearing in top of my website in every page,
Undefined index: email in C:\Apache24\htdocs\checkup.php on line 10

i have checked my mysql schema and coding but unable to find error please suggest me something to solve this error. 
[image]

**This is checkup.php page codding**

```php
<?php
include('dbconn.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 


$user_check=  $_SESSION['email'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT fullname, email FROM register WHERE email='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user = $row['email'];
$msguser = $row['fullname'];


?>
```

and this is login.php & loginconn.php page

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>online shopping</title>
<?php

 include 'header.php';

 include 'dbconn.php';
 include 'loginconn.php';



if ((isset($_SESSION['email']) != '')) 
{
header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
    <body>
<br>

<fieldset class="login_div">
 <legend>User Login</legend>


   <form method="POST" action="" >

  <table border="0"  cellspacing="10" >

  <tr>
<td><?php echo $error; ?></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="279"><center>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<label>Email:</label></td>
    <td width="385"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td><center>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<label>Password:</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="loginbtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php

    include("dbconn.php"); 

    $error = ""; 
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $error = "Both fields are required.";
        }else
        {

            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];


            $email = stripslashes($email);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$email);
            $password =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$password);
            $password = md5($password);


            $sql="SELECT id FROM register WHERE email='$_POST[$email]' and password='$_POST[$password]'";
            $result= mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


            if( mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                header("location: index.php"); 
            }
            else
            {
                $error = "Incorrect username or password.";
            }

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: use if(isset($_POST["submit"])) in checkup.php

Comment: again same error occurring

Comment: if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$user_check=  $_SESSION['email'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT fullname, email FROM register WHERE email='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user = $row['email'];
$msguser = $row['fullname'];
}

Comment: thanks much @CodeLove you solved my big problem but another problem is occuring when i tried to call elements from the same table its shows nothing no error no output
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT fullname, email FROM register WHERE email='$user_check' ");
 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 
$login_user = $row['email'];
$msguser = $row['fullname'];
}

Comment: use **or die(mysqli_error($db));**

Comment: @CodeLove please help me, where to  write this code "or die(mysqli_error($db));" 
The fullname is not displaying in page and not showing any error

Comment: $result= mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) or die(mysqli_error($db));

Answer (score 0):

you missed session_start() function call in file loginconn.php. Add the same code as in checkup.php:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you call checkup.php php page ?

Add the action: `<form method="POST" action="checkup.php" >` on your login page.

And test before any other test that the form has been submitted :

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { // other tests }
```

More important, you've forgotten the `session_start` at the beginning of the page :

```
session_start();
```

This will maintain the session and the variables of it.